# Equality in the sequence of increasing ranges.

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $T \in L(V)$. Let $n = \dim V$. Prove that

$\text{rangeT}^n = \text{rangeT}^{n+1} = \text{rangeT}^{n+2} = \dots$

I need help finishing this proof. This is what I have so far:

First prove that $\text{rangeT}^n = \text{rangeT}^{n+1}$

Suppose for the sake of contradiction the above statement is not true, then

$\text{rangeT}^n \subsetneq \text{rangeT}^{n+1} \subsetneq \text{rangeT}^{n+2} \subsetneq \dots$

In the strict inclusion chain above, the dimension increases by at least one every time which implies that $\text{dim rangeT}^{n+1} \geq n + 1$. However this is a contradiction since V cannot have dimension greater than n/

Now we must show that $\text{rangeT}^n = \text{rangeT}^{n+1} \implies \text{rangeT}^n = \text{rangeT}^{n+1} = \text{rangeT}^{n+2} = \dots$

Meaning that we must show that $\text{rangeT}^{m+k} = \text{rangeT}^{m+k+1}$ for all positive integers k.

To prove this, first we must show that

$\text{rangeT}^n \subset \text{rangeT}^{n+1} \subset \text{rangeT}^{n+2} \subset \dots$

Suppose $v \in \text{range T}^k$ which means that $T^ku = v$ for some $u, v \in V$

What I wanted to show at this point was that v is also in $\text{rangeT}^{k+1}$ and then use the above fact to show that $\text{rangeT}^{m+k} = \text{rangeT}^{m+k+1}$

If I can prove the middle part then I can say:

Prove $\text{rangeT}^{m+k} = \text{rangeT}^{m+k+1}$

We already know that $\text{rangeT}^{m+k} \subset \text{rangeT}^{m+k+1}$

Now we must show the inclusion in the other direction, suppose $v \in \text{rangeT}^{m+k+1}$

This means that $v = T^{m+k+1}u = T^{m+1}(T^ku)$ for some $u, v \in V$.

And again I get stuck on this part.

Sorry for the long proof I wanted to write it all out can someone help me complete this? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Cayley Hamilton theorem implies that $T^m$ can be written as a linear combination of $T,T^2,..T^n$. This implies the above result.

EDIT: The proof in detail:

C-H Thm. says that $T$ satisfies its own characteristic equation. The characteristic equation is of degree $n$.

Say, $T^n+a_1T^{n-1}+...+a_n=0$. So, $T^{n+1}=-(a_1T^n+...+a_nT)$ (multiplying by $T$ and rearranging). Proceed similarly for higher powers of $T$.

Comment: We aren't supposed to use the Cayley Hamilton Theorem for this, and I'm not sure I follow how you would do that?

Comment: @Soaps: I can write an easy proof using Cayley Hamilton. Do you want it?

Comment: It would nice to see just to see another way of doing this, although the section of my book where I found this question has not covered Cayley Hamilton yet so is the way I was doing this above just completely wrong, or unnecessarily long? Thank you though I would like to see the proof!

Comment: @Soaps: Your approach is correct. You can make it work- I had seen it done in some book.. but since it's long I prefer the C-H proof. Let me write it down.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r(T^m)$ be the range of $T^m$. Then you have in general $r(T^{m+1})\subset r(T^m)$, not the inverse. Now if you have $r(T^m)=r(T^{m+1})$ for an $m\leq n$, you have easily that $r(T^n)=r(T^{n+1})$. Now suppose that for all $m$, $0\leq m\leq n-1$, you have $r(T^{m+1})\subsetneq r(T^m)$. What can you say of the dimension of $r(T^m)$ and of $r(T^{m+1})$ for $0\leq m\leq n-1$ ?